# Demo Code on main page showing click not found

Tags: gtk, vala

I am trying to compile demonstration code on the main page of [Vala programming language](https://vala.dev/)

```
int main (string[] args) {
  var app = new Gtk.Application(
    "com.example.App",
    ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
  );
  
  app.activate.connect(() => {
    var win = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow(app);

    var btn = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Hello World");
    btn.click.connect(win.close);

    win.child = btn;
    win.present();
  });
  return app.run(args);
}
```

I am using following command:

```
$ valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 valademo.vala
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
valademo.vala:13.5-13.13: error: The name `click' does not exist in the context of `Gtk.Button'
    btn.click.connect(win.close);
    ^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably a typo, it should be `clicked` not `click`. You may want to raise an [issue with the website](https://github.com/vala-lang/vala-www/issues) or submit a pull request.

There are a couple of other problems. Firstly GTK+3 needs `win.show_all()`, but that has been [removed in GTK 4](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#widgets-are-now-visible-by-default).

Secondly the documentation for [`win.present()`](https://valadoc.org/gtk4/Gtk.Window.present.html) is advising that function shouldn't be used.

Here's a working example for GTK+3:

```vala
int main (string[] args) {
  var app = new Gtk.Application(
    "com.example.App",
    ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
  );

  app.activate.connect(() => {
    var win = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow(app);

    var btn = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Hello World");
    btn.clicked.connect(win.close);

    win.child = btn;
    win.show_all();
  });
  return app.run(args);
}
```